# question on measurability of a function

Tags: measure-theory

Let us define a function $f:[0,1]\to \ell_\infty[0,1]$ by $f(t)=\chi_{[0,t]}$. Here $\ell_\infty[0,1]$ stands for the space of all bounded functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$, where $[0,1]$ is endowed with the discrete topology and the corresponding $\sigma$-field is the power set over $[0,1]$ along with the counting measure on it. Where as the domain $[0,1]$ is endowed with the usual Lebesgue measure on it.

Q: Is it necessary that $f$ is measurable ?

Comment: Please explain what steps you've taken to solve the problem. For example, what went wrong when you tried to find tried to find a counterexample? What went wrong when trying to prove it?

Comment: The answer is undefined so far. Since $f$ is a map into $\ell_\infty[0,1]$ you need to say what $\sigma$-algebra on $\ell_\infty[0,1]$ you're talking about. Specifying a $\sigma$-algebra on $[0,1]$ is irrelevant, since $f$ is not a map into $[0,1]$.

Comment: $\ell_\infty[0,1]$ is a Banach space, so we are considering the Borel $\sigma$-field over it. So my question is whether inverse image of open set is measurable or not.

Comment: This function is not continuous. For any two $s, t\in [0,1]$ we have $\|\chi_{[0,s]}-\chi_{[0,t]}\|=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out we're talking about $\ell_\infty[0,1]$ with the uniform norm, making the bit about the discrete topology on $[0,1]$ irrelevant.

Anyway, no $f$ is not measurable. If $E$ is any subset of $[0,1]$ there is an open set $V$ with $E=f^{-1}(V)$, namely $$V=\bigcup_{t\in E}B(f(t),1/3).$$

Similarly for any function into any metric space with $d(f(t),f(s))=1$ for all $s\ne t$.